# How to use PersistJS with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, persistjs

I'm trying to use the [PersistJS](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js) library with ReactJS but I get a lot of errors, what do I need to change in order to make it work ?

Already tried to put the persist.min.js with the index.html from public folder this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/persist-min.js'></script>
...
```

But when I call it from any component, with this code:

```
var store = new Persist.Store('My Application');
```

I get this error

```
'Persist' is not defined  no-undef
```

The same error appears when I try to import directly from the component this way:

```
import "../../utils/persist-min";
```

I also tried the approach suggested by *franciscomemoli* on [this issue](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js/issues/40) on the library's github, but I get this error:

```
./src/js/persist.js
  Line 31:    'google' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 40:    'GearsFactory' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 44:    'ActiveXObject' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 76:     'google' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 79:     'google' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 80:     'google' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 89:     'Persist' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 492:   'google' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 603:   'globalStorage' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 622:   'globalStorage' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 924:   'swfobject' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 932:   'swfobject' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 957:   'swfobject' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1098:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
```

What am I doing wrong and how can this library be imported inside a React app ?

Comment: You should ignore any third-party code from linting. So here, just ignore `persist.js`.

Comment: Why is the path in index.html different from the path in your component?

Comment: Emile, when I remove the file from the linter, the no-undef error (for google, globalStorage...) is gone, but I get this error: 'Persist' is not defined  no-undef (using the last approach I told on the question).

Isaac, this happens because they are in different locations, the component and the index.html from the public folder of the ReactJS project

Comment: `no-undef` lint error is not a problem, it's just a tool. Since PersistJS is an old lib, it just creates a new global named `Persist`, which you can just tell your linter about. With [eslint, you can specify custom globals.](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals)

Comment: Oh, it worked. Thank you !!